# MacBook Pro 15'' Retina Mid-2015: Upgrade RAM to 32Gb

Tags: macbook-pro

Is this possible?

I read on the crucial.com website that it is not.

I imagine 2x16Gb would be a bit expensive but not unheard of.

Answer (score 13):

It's not that the amount of RAM doesn't exist, it's that the upgradeability doesn't exist. The Retina MacBook Pro's RAM is soldered to the motherboard. Nothing is getting in or out.

Comment: Make sense then...

Comment: additionally, the Haswell processor and chipset in that computer only support a maximum of 16GB of RAM (and it is soldered onto the board, so it's moot anyway).